# Where does Array get its toList method

Tags: scala

Through searches, I understand the way (or, a way) to convert an Array to a List is like so:

```
val l = Array(1, 2, 3).toList
```

But not only can I not find the toList method in Array's API docs, I can't find it in anything that seems to be an ancestor or inherited trait of Array.

Using the newer 2.9 API docs, I see that toList exists in these things:

```
ImmutableMapAdaptor ImmutableSetAdaptor IntMap List ListBuffer LongMap 
MutableList Option ParIterableLike PriorityQueue Stack StackProxy 
StreamIterator SynchronizedSet SynchronizedStack TraversableForwarder 
TraversableOnce TraversableOnceMethods TraversableProxyLike
```

But I can't understand how toList gets from one of these to be part of Array. Can anyone explain this?

Comment: If it's anything like Java, it's an class method of the Array class.

Comment: That's the thing, not seeing it: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Array.html

Comment: Yes, I noticed that too... maybe poor docs??

Comment: @John It is not anything like Java.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`toList` and similar methods not natively found on Java arrays (including our old favourites, map, flatMap, filter etc.) come from [`s.c.m.ArrayOps`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/rc/scala/collection/mutable/ArrayOps.html), which arrays acquire via implicit conversions in [scala.Predef](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/scala/Predef$.html).  Look for implicit methods whose names end with `ArrayOps` and you'll see where the magic comes from.

Comment: Huh. And that ArrayOps isn't showing up yet as containing toList in that index for methods starting with T: http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/index/index-t.html

Comment: Try compiling with `scalac -print` to *really* see the magic.

Comment: @dino 'Cause the ref index don't show inherited members. toList is defined in TransversableOnce.

Comment: @dino If that index where to contain all classes which have the method, be they defined or inherited, it would be useless by excess of information. It's presence in `TraversableOnce` guarantees it is present on every collection plus iterators, so instead of having a 19 classes, it would have dozens. By comparison, filtering by `Array` shows 16 traits and classes. Filtering by `String`, which also features `toList` through implicits, shows only 5.

Comment: @Daniel C. Sobral: Not sure what the solution is, but I feel like it's difficult to find information like this in the API. And that's not a good thing.

Comment: @dino Scala has implicits, which is quite unique. One have to get used to their existence and how to handle it. The easiest way is let the REPL tell you -- IntelliJ will do that. Second to that, you have to be aware what is in scope by default in Scala, and what is being imported in the code you are looking at. All packages, objects, traits and classes from scala and scala.runtime are in scope by default, and all of scala.Predef is imported. To find implicits, search a implicit def from the type you have in that scope, and whatever else is imported.

Comment: @dino Java was also pretty confusing for me at the beginning, since I couldn't just type `man method` like I did in C. One has to learn the tool one is using...